# Get signer email from a Template Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

A little bit of background as to what my goal is and why I need to get the email from the Template (just in case there is a better way):

I added three signers to a docusign template I created, one who is supposed to get the information from my code and two who I have entered their info directly into the email fields. My issue is that when I look at the SDK/API I don't see a way to add the missing email\name and use the default information I added in the Docusign dashboard for the Template.

The solution I came up with was to get a list of the signers from the Template (to add them to the Envelope), but I am not seeing a way to do that in their documentation. Any help provided would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to use the 'Placeholder' feature already ? (https://www.docusign.com/DocuSignHelp/Content/create-templates.htm)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this before. However, that is the feature I was using, but it looked like I still needed to send the signer info when creating an envelope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of signers from the template using below call

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients
```

Details are available at, [TemplateRecipients: list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateRecipients/list/).

Comment: Thanks so much! I am really surprised I missed this in the docs yesterday, I must have been having an air head moment